# How to make matrix factorization fast with sparse matrices?

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Currently, I am working on a problem where I have to factorize a matrix $A\approx PQ$ which is sparse and has a dimension on the order of $1 \text{ million}^2.$ I have implemented the following version of matrix factorization:

1. Initialize matrices $P$ and $Q$ with random values.
2. For each iteration do the following:

   - Iterate over all triples $(i,j,A[i][j])$ where $A[i][j]>0$ and compute the corresponding entry in the matrix $PQ$ denoted as $[PQ]_{ij}.$ Find $e = A[i][i]-[PQ]_{ij}$ and use this to update the row vector $P[i][:]$ and column vector $Q[:][j].$ Finally check the global error by computing the $||A-PQ||$ and see if it is less than $0.0001.$ If the condition holds then we break otherwise we carry on.

The problem is that if $A_{m\times n } = P_{m\times k}Q_{k\times n}$ where $m,n\approx 10^6$ and $k\approx 10^2$ then computing $||A-PQ||$ is expensive. Maybe there is a way to make this fast. Perhaps we could define an error function for a block matrix.